# Accessing "alternate text" for an image via PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, accessibility, pdfbox

Is there some way to extract "alternate text" for a specific image using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)?

I have a PDF file which, as described at http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/2011/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20110621/pdf.html#PDF1, has had alternate text added to an image. Using PDFBox I can find my way through the object model to the image itself (a PDXObjectImage) through PDFDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages() [iterator] .getResources.getImages() but I can not see any way to get from the image itself to the alternate text for it.

A small sample PDF (with a single image which has some alternate text specified) can be found at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12253279/image_test_pass.pdf (It should say "This is the alternate text for the image.").

Comment: Matt, what are you trying to do? Convert the PDF to another format? *The PDFBox link doesn't work for me*

Comment: My aim is to automatically check that every image has some "alternate text" associated with it as part of an accessibility checking tool.

Comment: Hi @MattSheppard! Did you find a solution? It would be really helpful for me to get some information from you. Thanks, Gábor

Comment: I ended up with something based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/12557302/797 which recursively walks down, and also a check for any page.getResources().getXObjectNames() where isImageXObject on the page's resources returns true.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how/if this can be done with PDFBox, but I can tell you that this feature is related to the sections of the PDF Spec called Logical Structutre/Tagged PDF, which is not fully supported in every PDF tool out-there.

Assuming it is supported by the tool you are using, you will have to follow 4 main steps to retrieve this information (I will use the sample PDF file you posted for the following explanation).

Assuming you have access to the internal structure of the PDF file, you will need to:

1- Parse the page content and find the MCID number of the Tag element that wraps the image you are interested in.

Page content:

```
BT
/P <</MCID 0 >>BDC 
/GS0 gs
/TT0 1 Tf
0.0004 Tc -0.0028 Tw 10.02 0 0 10.02 90 711 Tm
(This is an image test )Tj
EMC 
ET
/Figure <</MCID 1 >>BDC 
q
106.5 0 0 106.5 90 591.0599976 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
EMC
```

Your image:
[image]

2- In the page object, retrieve the key StructParents.
[image]

3- Now retrieve the Structure Tree (key StructTreeRoot of the Catalog object, which is the root object in every PDF file), and inside it, the ParentTree.

4- The ParentTree starts with an array where you can find pairs of elements (See Number Trees in the PDF Spec for more details). In this specific tree, the first element of each pair is a numeric value that corresponds to the StructParents key retrieved in step 2, and the second element is an array of objects, where the indexes correspond to the MCID values retreived in step 1. So, You will search here the element that corresponds to the MCID value of your image, and you will find a PDF object. Inside this object, you will find the alternate text.

[image]

Looks easy, isn't it?

*Tools used in this answer:

PDF Vole (based on iText)

Amyuni PDF Analyzer*

Answer (score 0):

Eric from the PDFBox mailing list sent me the following, though I've not tested it out yet...

---

Hi,

For your test file, here is a way to access "/Alt" entry :

```
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("image_test_pass.pdf");
    PDStructureTreeRoot treeRoot =
        document.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot();

    // get page for each StructElement
    for (Object o : treeRoot.getKids()) {
        if (o instanceof PDStructureElement) {
            PDStructureElement structElement = (PDStructureElement)o;
            System.out.println(structElement.getAlternateDescription());
            PDPage page = structElement.getPage();
            if (page != null) {
                page.getResources().getImages();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please refer to the PDF specification http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf and in particular §14.6, §14.7,
§14.9.3 and §14.9.4 to know all the rules in order to find the "/Alt"
entry. There seems to have several way to define this information.

BR,
Eric

Comment: This code may work for the specific file that you sent,but not for every possible pdf

Comment: There are many issues with this code: 1- It will only show elements at the first level of the tree, and we all know that a tree is not a list. 2- With this approach there is no direct association of the alternate text of an image with its corresponding image. 3- The page attribute in StructElement object is optional, so you may not even have a page association.