# Accessing alt-text for an image in a PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, accessibility, pdfbox

I'm looking for a way to access alt text for images in a PDF automatically, using [PDFBox](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox). I know that you can manually extract the alt text using the other tools, but I'm looking for a way to do this at scale. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525883/accessing-alternate-text-for-an-image-via-pdfbox) addressing this issue, but it seems outdated. How do I extract alt-text for images in a PDF using PDFBox?

Edit: This is what I have so far, but it is still returning null on a pdf that I know has alt text on the figures.

```
PDFMarkedContentExtractor extractor = new PDFMarkedContentExtractor();
for (int p = 1; p <= document.getNumberOfPages(); ++p) {
        PDPage page = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(p);
        extractor.processPage(page);
        List<PDMarkedContent> annotations = extractor.getMarkedContents();
        // do some nice output with a header
        String pageStr = String.format("page %d:", p);
        System.out.println(pageStr);
        for (int i = 0; i < pageStr.length(); ++i) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < annotations.size(); i++) {
         System.out.println(annotations.get(i).getAlternateDescription());
            }
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: That answer isn't that bad... download PDFDebugger and have a look at your file. (click "view", "show internal structure" and you'll see the structure tree after expanding stuff). Sadly this whole thing is quite tricky. I'm a pdfbox committer and I have barely touched it.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Is there any way to access the alt text besides doing a full tree search on PDFDebugger? I tested on [this PDF](https://github.com/martinlovell/accessible-pdfbox-example/blob/master/test.pdf) and the Alt tag was under `Page:1 / Resources / Properties / Prop1/ Alt` while the image was under  `Page:1 / Resources / Properties / XObject / Im1`. I also tried this on a PDF with alt text added post-hoc using the Adobe Accessibility tool and was unable to find an Alt tag at all, but maybe it's buried elsewhere.

Comment: Wow, that looks easy. What I found is the same text, but here: Root/StructTreeRoot/K/K/[0]/K/[0]/Alt

Comment: Testing PDFs with alt text added through MS Word, Adobe, PAVE, Google Docs, and PDFBox, it looks like PDFDebugger will only extract alt text if the PDF was originally generated using PDFBox. Otherwise, it doesn't look like it's extracting the alt text.

Comment: PDFDebugger doesn't "extract" alt text at all, it just shows what's in the PDF tree.

Comment: @Isabel You can find the alt tags in the Adobe Accessibility tools opening the tag tree, right clicking the figure tag and select properties. I tested this with your PDF above.

PDFDebugger shows alt tags created from other sources as well, if they are in the Document Tree. I just tested that with a Word -> PDF document. Just make sure you select the View > Show Internal Structure of PDF Debugger.